# How to open view-code modal that contains the source code in grapesjs?

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

I just started using grapesjs and I'm trying tobuild a simple web builder using grapesjs, I customized my editor's UI.
I'm trying to add a view code button similar to the one in [grapesjs Demo](https://grapesjs.com/demo.html) that shows the source code in a modal like this one
[grapesjs code modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPLaG.png)

right now I added the export button to my panel

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
  ...
  // panels config
  panels: {
    defaults: [
      {
        id: "basic-actions",
        el: "#actions",
        buttons: [
          {
            id: "visibility",
            active: true,
            label: "<i class='fa-solid fa-eye'></i>",
            command: "sw-visibility",
          },
          {
            id: "save",
            label: "<i class='fa fa-paper-plane btn-save'></i>",
            command: "save-project",
          },
          {
            id: "cmd-clear",
            label: "<i class='fa-solid fa-trash'></i>",
            command: "cmd-clear",
          },
          {
            id: "undo",
            label: "<i class='fa-solid fa-undo'></i>",
            command: "undo",
          },
          {
            id: "redo",
            label: "<i class='fa-solid fa-redo'></i>",
            command: "redo",
          },
          {
            id: "export",
            label: "<i class='fa-solid fa-download'></i>",
            command: "export",
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
})
```

now I'm want to set the code to "export" command so I can show that modal
here I'm stuck

```
editor.Commands.add('export', {
  run: (editor) => {
    // what to do ???
    console.log(editor.getHtml())
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the official documentaion

```
{
    id: "export",
    label: "<i class='fa-solid fa-download'></i>",
    command: "export-template",
    context: "export-template",
},
```

and it solves my problem. and about downloading the files I used [this plugin](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-plugin-export)